# EKEventStore issues

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, ekeventstore

I'm completely new to EKEventStore and just found out it existed last week. In my app which saves events I want to be able to save an event to my phones calendar. How do I get that to pop up with the saved event data?

My current event store controller class

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

class EventController: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = EventController ()
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

override init() {

    //grants permission to access calendar

    if EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Event) != (EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {

        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: { (granted, error) -> Void in


        })
    } else {


    }

}

//creates event

func createEvent(title: String, startDate: NSDate) {

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

    if (EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Event) != EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {

        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: { (granted, error) -> Void in

            event.title = title
            event.startDate = startDate
            //        event.endDate = endDate
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

            do {

                try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .FutureEvents)

            } catch {
                print("bad things happened")
            }

        })
    }
}
```

}

Calling the save method from another class

```
@IBAction func addToCalendar(sender: AnyObject) {

    EventController.sharedInstance.createEvent(event.eventTitle!, startDate: event.eventDate!)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks!